# MySQL: Use data from one table to fill a second table using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

SQL conundrum here.

I want to populate an empty table based on the data in an existing table using phpMyAdmin.

More specifically, I want to use the data in `mark` to create the data in `attempt`. The columns in mark are student_number, test_number, attempt_number, question_number and the answer. It's a multiple-choice test analysis tool.

```
mark (existing)
snum     tnum    anum    qnum    answer
----------------------------------------
1        1        1        1       A
1        1        1        2       C
1        1        1        3       D
1        1        2        1       B    
1        1        2        2       A
1        1        2        3       C


attempt (to be created)
snum     tnum    anum    period
--------------------------------
1        1        1        2013-1      
1        1        2        2013-2
```

I can get the distinct snum, tnum, anum combinations as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT snum, tnum, anum FROM `mark`
```

How can I use the results from this call to populate the requisite insert call?

```
INSERT INTO `attempt` (snum,tnum,anum,period) VALUES (:s,:t,:a,"2013-1")
```

Ideally, I'd like to auto-complete the period value based on "2013-" plus the anum. I suspect this is not possible, so I'll just select all the `anum=1` values, and hardcode the period value (and then repeat for each `anum`).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "INSERT INTO SELECT" syntax:

```
INSERT INTO 'attempt'(snum,tnum,anum,period) SELECT DISTINCT snum,tnum,anum,CONCAT('2013-',anum) as period FROM mark;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `attempt`
            (snum,
             tnum,
             anum,
             period)
select DISTINCT
  snum,
  tnum,
  anum,
  concat('2013-',anum) as period
from mark;
```